# Ubuntu won't boot in Asus X554L

Tags: boot, asus

I've been having problems with this laptop since nearly a year ago. At first -  I bought it with Windows 8.1 installed - I had OpenSuse and Windows running together and it was all fine until it decided to start giving me problems with booting: it would not boot openSuse again (no Grub anymore or whoever it's named in openSuse) and would need several tries to boot Windows. It just would not recognize the booting space or something, and it would boot one out of 10 times...

So I finally sent the laptop to repair, everything was quite fast and they gave my laptop back saying they changed whichever part of it (not hard drive of something alike, some kind of peripheral if I recall well - really didn't check it thoroughly). This was a few weeks ago. Then I simply installed Ubuntu - without Windows this time - and it worked pretty well these last weeks (it would need like two attempts to make it boot, but it was okay to me), until today. I tried to turn on the laptop and, sadly, the same thing happens again. It doesn't boot Grub anymore, just goes directly to the EFI as it doesn't find any boot device. In the EFI, one out of ten times - roughly, ofc - the Ubuntu boot device DOES appear, even though the laptop was not able to boot it, but most times, as I say, it does not appear.

So, I just tried to run the Boot Repair (Boot Repair Disk) and see if it might help me. It returned the following pastebin link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23659333/ - I am not that good at systems to understand it perfectly, though. It really didn't help, as it changed nothing at all, the laptop keeps just taking me to the EFI (or BIOS, whoever you want to call it), and sometimes I see the Ubuntu's hard drive, and sometimes I don't.

Any more troubleshooting? Do you think this is definitely a hardware problem, or some compatibility issue, or...? I am really getting sick of it and I'd like to solve it ASAP...

Thank you very much for your help!

Josep.

Comment: How did you setup dual boot in the first place.

Comment: I really don't know, I just sort of followed opensuse's default installation process I guess... The weirdest thing I could've done is to use a custom partition, which I guess wouldn't differ much...